# Select more than record count by duplicating records

Tags: mysql, sql

**Problem:** A questions table has 100 records. A dynamically created test requires 110 questions. It is ok to duplicate questions.

**FYI:** Selecting question ID's only using MySQL.

I know I can easily achieve this with a programming language but my requirements require an SQL solution.

**EDIT:**

Randomly selected records.

The number of duplicates should be kept to a minimum. That is: until there is a requirement to duplicate duplicates - don't. I can only see the need to duplicate duplicates when the test requires over twice the amount of questions available.

**EDIT:**

Not all tests will require more than the questions available. However this is not known until the test is compiled.

**logic:** `select ID from questions` .... limit $dynamicNumberOfQuestions

The query should address a test requiring 50 questions (less that the number of questions available) as well as 110 questions (more than the number of questions available) as well as 300 (more than double the amount of questions available). If that be possible.

Comment: Your post does not make any sense.

Comment: Do you want to duplicate randomly, or is it all right to get the same duplicates each time? Also, is there some multiple of the original questions that you can say is your maximum limit of questions ever needed for a single test?

Comment: How "almost unqiue" do you want the questions to be? How many of the questions could be excluded? Is it ok to repeat the same question more than twice? Would for example the same question repeated 110 times be a valid result (as it would be if picked completely by random)?

Comment: I think the user wants to select all the 100 records + an extra 10?

Comment: @Matt: That means that all questions are always on every test, which might no be desirable.

Comment: Yeh some random aspect should be considered

Comment: Updated my question based on comments.

Answer (score 4):

If it is `MYSQL` then this should get what you want

```
SELECT * FROM questiontable
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM questiontable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

Comment: + "top 110" and this is the answer I was about to write. That is, get the 110, then shuffle ALL of them, so the dupes aren't ALWAYS in the last ten.

Comment: Where would that need to be added?

Comment: so put query in a sub query and use sleect top 110?

Comment: Yes exactly. I would write an answer but you were faster and you deserve the rep.

Comment: Would this address my second edit? I should have made my question more specific.

Comment: This solution does work as desired by changing the limit to the desired number. However, if the total number of questions required is over twice the amount of questions available (if 210 questions are required) it does not work (my fault for not making that a requirement at first).

Comment: when you need to have more than double you could add another UNION ALL  line on to the query

Comment: Would there be a more portable way, as it would not be known how many unions were required. Granted, this 'over double' requirement would probably never happen, but never say never.

Comment: is the amount of questions required stored anywhere or is it simply decided

Comment: stored in another table based upon a test code entered by the user.

Comment: are the tables linked in anyway?